# how to loop through a set of elements with a data attribute value using jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to loop through a set of elements with a data attribute value using jquery? I tried this...
         alert(variableName); // works

```
    $("SectionATable tr [data-testlog='"+variableName+"']").each(function()
    {
                alert("sectionA log");
    });
```

No error shows up in firebug....

Comment: `data-testlog` is assigned to `TR` or to the children `TD` elements? and also are you missing an `#` ?

Comment: perhaps you mean `#SectionATable` as `SectionATable` wouldn't be a tagname. also, when you are working with selectors it helps to show the html that it is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you had a few small syntax errors, try this:

```
$("#SectionATable tr [data-testlog="+variableName+"]").each(function(){
    alert("sectionA log");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]

here are selecotrs
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/